# d3 data constancy

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is a followup of this question on SO: [D3 - issues on first transition after initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738424/d3-issues-on-first-transition-after-initialization).

I have studies and implemented the key functions as explained by Mike and Jason in their answers. I also found this blog post useful http://knowledgestockpile.blogspot.com/2012/01/understanding-selectall-data-enter.html

I have used a key like

```
.data(svg.chartData, function(d) { return d.idSeries;})
```

to map one-to-one data and index.

However, I do not get the expected result and data points swap on redraw. Please have a look at http://jsbin.com/avoced/8/edit, specifically to the following relevant functions:

Chart initialization:

```
    svg.series = svg.selectAll(".series").data(svg.chartData, function(d) { return d.idSer;})
    svg.series.enter().append("g").classed("series", true)

    svg.rects = svg.series.selectAll("rect").data(Object, function(d) { return d.x;})
    svg.rects.enter().append("rect")
```

Redraw:

```
    svg.series = svg.selectAll(".series").data(svg.chartData, function(d) { return d.idSer;})
    svg.series.enter().append("g").classed("series", true)
    svg.series.exit().remove()

    svg.rects = svg.series.selectAll("rect").data(Object, function(d) { return d.x;})
    svg.rects.enter().append("rect")
    svg.rects.exit().remove()
```

Scales:

```
x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(svg.pointsNames, function(d) { return d;}) 
        .rangeRoundBands([0,width], .1);
```

What am I missing here?

Many thanks